# How to store backslash+dollar-sign ("/$") in R?

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to generate a script using R. I want the script to include the following command:

> GPU0=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader,nounits | awk 'NR==1{print$1/100}')

If i want to do this in the terminal, I would execute the following command:

> echo "GPU0=\$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader,nounits | awk 'NR==1{print$1/100}')" >> test.txt

Hence I execute the following command in R console:

> system("echo GPU0=\$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader,nounits | awk 'NR==1{print$1/100}') >> test.txt")

But I got the following error message:

> Error: '\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""echo GPU0=\$"

Is there anything I can do to execute commands containing "\$" in R?

Edit: I'm using Linux.

Comment: On another note, you can get rid of `awk` entirely. `nvidia-smi` supports an option called `-i`. You can run `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader,nounits -i 0`.

Comment: @anishsane Thanks for the advice! Getting rid of the single quote may make things much easier in the future.

Comment: I don't think you need a backslash before the `$` sign.
Plus, quite possibly, `R` uses `/bin/sh` for running `system`. Instead of `$(...)` try using back-quotes. `echo GPU0=\`nvidia-smi -i 0 ... \` >>test.txt`

Comment: @anishsane Without the backslash, the terminal would execute everything inside the parentheses. So instead of  `GPU0=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader,nounits | awk 'NR==1{print$1/100}')` I got `GPU0=0` in `test.txt`

Comment: Just don't use a backslash

Comment: I think I've found the solution: `system("echo 'GPU0=\`nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader,nounits -i 0\`' >> test.txt")` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nah I think I was wrong. The command does not work

Comment: Doesn't R have any facilities for writing to a file, so that you can avoid using `system` in the first place? (I don't know R, but the `cat` function looks promising.) Part of your problem is that the entire argument to `echo` (`GPU0=$(...)`) should be quoted as well, which results in too many levels of quoting to handle comfortably.

Comment: @chepner Yes, the `cat` function does work in R! Thanks!